# Cannot find variable in the local class

Tags: java, computer-science

Please give me a hand to tell me why second for loop 'row' could not be found in the printSeating Method.

```
 public void printSeating()
    {
        for (int row = FIRST_ROW_NUMBER; row <= firstClass.length; row++)
        {
            if (row < 10)
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(row);
            System.out.println(":" + firstClass[row - FIRST_ROW_NUMBER]);
            }
    int firstEconomyRowNumber = FIRST_ROW_NUMBER + firstClassRowCount;
    int lastEconomyRowNumber = firstEconomyRowNumber + economyRowCount - 1;

        for (int row = firstEconomyRowNumber; 
                row <= lastEconomyRowNumber; row++);
        {
            if (row < 10)
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(row);
            System.out.println(":" + economy[row - firstEconomyRowNumber]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error.

```
for (int row = firstEconomyRowNumber; 
                row <= lastEconomyRowNumber; row++);
```

get rid of that `;` after the for loop and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

When declaring the FOR loop, you put a semicolon after the loop, like this:

```
for (int row = firstEconomyRowNumber; 
                row <= lastEconomyRowNumber; row++);{
//..insert code here
}
```

This declares a FOR loop without a body, so when you access the variable row after this statement, it cannot find the variable because it can only be used in the non-existent body of the FOR loop. To fix this, you would need to delete the semicolon, like so:

```
for (int row = firstEconomyRowNumber; 
                row <= lastEconomyRowNumber; row++){
//...insert code here
}
```